# execute a script from Run command box with directory in parametres Python

Tags: python

i want to execute a python script with 3 parameters via Run command box so i tried this :

```
cmd /k ""C:\Python27\u.py" "http://www.example.com" "param1" "3" "
```

and i get this error :

```
C:\Windows\system32
http://www.example.com
param1
3.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\u.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(txt) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '3.txt'
```

i used :

```
import os; print os.getcwd()
```

and as we see i get : `C:\Windows\system32`

and there is the problem the text file "3.txt" in the script directory and the Run command runs the script from  C:\Windows\system32 assuming that the the file is there `C:\Windows\system32\3.txt`

but in fact the text file "3.txt" is in the script directory `C:\Python27\`

(Ps : when i execute the same script with the cmd windows it works fine.)

any idea to execute the script with the parameters correctly via Run command box in the script directory?
i tried :

`cmd /k ""cd ../../python27/"  "C:\Python27\u.py" "http://www.example.com" "param1" "3" "`

and i get :

`The syntax of the file name, directory or volume is incorrect.`

Answer (score 0):

start -> run

`C:\Python27\python.exe  c:\python27\u.py "http://www.asd.cs" param1 3`

should work I would think ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping those inner double quotes ?

```
cmd /k "\"C:\Python27\u.py\" \"http://www.example.com\" \"param1\" \"3\" "
```